# How to convert dbf to raster the short way?

Tags: raster, convert, interpolation, dbf

I have got a dbf file and I want make it to raster file but the short way,

Look at my long way,

1. First i add my dbf file
2. and i create tin 
   http://i1211.photobucket.com/albums/cc421/mtnkou/2.jpg
3. at the and my raster file (tin to raster)
   http://i1211.photobucket.com/albums/cc421/mtnkou/3.jpg

How can I do  dbf to raster with short way,

i don't want create tin file,

Just dbf to raster,

How can i do ?

Comment: Could you answer some questions to clarify your question? Are you using ESRI products (ArcMap, ArcCatalog, etc.)? If so, is your 'dbf' file a feature class (in a geodatabase) or a shapefile?

Comment: Also what does the .dbf contain? XYZ coords of point features?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains XYZ cords of point features. General process to create raster from  point features is: point features -> interpolation of the space between the points (depends on the typ of data you have, usually you do some trials to see what effects suits you most) -> raster.

Your procedure above (points -> TIN -> raster) is actually one of the simplest for of raster creation, as TIN is actual interpolation step.

If you want to have more control during the interpolation ArcGIS, QGIS or from command line with GDAL will offer you some other tools. QGIS mostly is the GUI for GDAL. I guess what is your main concern, is interpolation algorithm. TIN does use linear interpolation between points without any influence of the neighboring values (in my opinon most suitable for terrain), IDW on the other hand is influenced by other neighbors (which is good with statistics etc.).

Comment: All I am saying that it would be one of the ways. I'd use it for terrain, though for statistics I'd use some other approach. I'm not sure what you mean by "long" way, as its simply 3 step process, which can be further decreased by use of model builder or script ie. in Python.